# Regex for finding/adding string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have these type of texts in a .txt file

```
rpad(SomeText, 2, \' \') , rpad(SomeTexxt, 18, \' \')
```

I want these to be converted as

```
nvl(rpad(SomeText, 2, \' \'),\'$$\') , nvl(rpad(SomeTexxt, 18, \' \'),\'$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\')
```

How can i do this with PHP ??
 the newly added $'s should be as many as the number like 2 or 18.

Comment: You will need to give some more information for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: I see what you need, but could you give more examples of what may be in the text file to be converted to see the variance?

Comment: hi. in my text file there are certain strings which starts with rpad and followed by sometext and then a number and ends with \' \').
I want these to be transformed as nvl(rpad and the same till \' \') and then followed by $'s as many the number which is in between.

Comment: this text file structure is strict? or may be text looks like: 
`rpad(SomeText, 2, \' \') , some other text bla bla rpad(SomeTexxt, 18, \' \')`
?

Comment: yes. OTARIKI ..
same. this rpad's are in middle of the texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`pre_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function here.

```
$str="rpad(SomeText, 2, \' \') , rpad(SomeTexxt, 18, \' \')";
echo preg_replace_callback("~rpad\(\w+,\h*(\d+),[^)]*\)~", function($m){
    return 'nvl('.$m[0].",\'".str_repeat("$", $m[1])."\')";
}
, $str);
```

`(\d+)` captures the number which was present just after to the somtext and later it was used to repeat the `$` symbol some number of times according to the number captured.

**Output:**

```
nvl(rpad(SomeText, 2, \' \'),\'$$\') , nvl(rpad(SomeTexxt, 18, \' \'),\'$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\')
```

Comment: Hi avinash, thanks for ur reply. it worked for the example i gave. but for my actual case its not working for some reason :( this is how my string looks like 

rpad(lookup_ext([DM_W1_XREF.DM_W1_XREF.XREF_VKORG_VTWEG, \'PRE_LOAD_CACHE\', \'MAX\'], [ VKORG_NEW ], [  NULL  ], [ SYSTEM_NAME, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.SYSTEM_NAME, VKORG_OLD, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.VKORG ]) 
SET(\"output_cols_info\" = \'<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><output_cols_info><col index=\"1\" expression=\"no\"/>
</output_cols_info>\', \"run_as_separate_process\" = \'no\'), 4, \' \')

Comment: @Tirumalesh ask it as another question with an exact string as example.

Comment: Hi avinash. here is the new question, can u pls try this. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403766/regex-for-find-and-replacing-a-string-in-php