# regex for find and replacing a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have these type of texts in a .txt file

```
rpad(lookup_ext([DM_W1_XREF.DM_W1_XREF.XREF_VKORG_VTWEG, \'PRE_LOAD_CACHE\', \'MAX\'], [ VKORG_NEW ], [  NULL  ], [ SYSTEM_NAME, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.SYSTEM_NAME, VKORG_OLD, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.VKORG ]) 
SET("output_cols_info" = \'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><output_cols_info><col index="1" expression="no"/>
</output_cols_info>\', "run_as_separate_process" = \'no\'), 4, \' \')
```

I want these to be converted as

```
nvl(rpad(lookup_ext([DM_W1_XREF.DM_W1_XREF.XREF_VKORG_VTWEG, \'PRE_LOAD_CACHE\', \'MAX\'], [ VKORG_NEW ], [  NULL  ], [ SYSTEM_NAME, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.SYSTEM_NAME, VKORG_OLD, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.VKORG ]) 
SET("output_cols_info" = \'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><output_cols_info><col index="1" expression="no"/>
</output_cols_info>\', "run_as_separate_process" = \'no\'), 4, \' \'),'$$$$')
```

How can i do this with PHP ?? the newly added $'s should be as many as the number like 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be possible through `preg_replace_callback` function.

```
$str= <<< EOT
rpad(lookup_ext([DM_W1_XREF.DM_W1_XREF.XREF_VKORG_VTWEG, \'PRE_LOAD_CACHE\', \'MAX\'], [ VKORG_NEW ], [  NULL  ], [ SYSTEM_NAME, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.SYSTEM_NAME, VKORG_OLD, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.VKORG ]) 
SET("output_cols_info" = \'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><output_cols_info><col index="1" expression="no"/>
</output_cols_info>\', "run_as_separate_process" = \'no\'), 4, \' \')
EOT;
echo preg_replace_callback("~(?s)rpad\(.*?,\h*(\d+),\h*\\\\'\h*\\\\'\)~", function($m){
    return 'nvl('.$m[0].",'".str_repeat("$", $m[1])."')";
}
    , $str);
```

**Output:**

```
nvl(rpad(lookup_ext([DM_W1_XREF.DM_W1_XREF.XREF_VKORG_VTWEG, \'PRE_LOAD_CACHE\', \'MAX\'], [ VKORG_NEW ], [  NULL  ], [ SYSTEM_NAME, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.SYSTEM_NAME, VKORG_OLD, \'=\', T_M67_A033_EXT.VKORG ]) 
SET("output_cols_info" = \'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><output_cols_info><col index="1" expression="no"/>
</output_cols_info>\', "run_as_separate_process" = \'no\'), 4, \' \'),'$$$$')
```

Answer (score 0):

there is possible many technique to achieve your target.

This is most simple, you regex could be your regex

```
rpad(.*?)\\'\s\\\\'\)
```

And this could be your replace string

```
rpad(val\1,'$$$$')
```

Enjoy